# Why isn't my score updating in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, game-development

I have tried many ways to keep score but nothing seems to be working. I have had it as a separate function, in the start function and now in the createImage function to no avail. Can anyone please help me fix my code so that the score increases by 1 if the user clicks on the green ball (at array index 0)?

```js
var imagesArray = new Array(5);
imagesArray[0] = "./green-ball.png";
imagesArray[1] = "./yellow-ball.png";
imagesArray[2] = "./blue-ball.png";
imagesArray[3] = "./light-pink-ball.png";
imagesArray[4] = "./purple-ball.png";

let score = 0;
let timer = 15;
var interval;
let timeLeft = 15;
let lastScore = 0;

var img = document.createElement("img")
const images = document.getElementsByClassName(imagesArray);
var game = document.getElementById("game");


function gameOver() {
    var lastScoreElement = document.getElementById("lastScore");
    clearInterval(timer);
    clearInterval(interval);

    $("#playAgainButton").show();
    $("#lastScore").show(
        lastScoreElement.textContent = " " + score
    );
    ResetGlobalVariables;
}

function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createImage() {
    img.src = imagesArray[random(0, imagesArray.length - 1)];
    img.width = random(50, 200);
    img.height = random(50, 200);
    img.style.left = random(0, 800 - img.width) + "px";
    img.style.top = random(0, 600 - img.height) + "px";
    return img;
    for (i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
        imagesArray[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
            score++;
            var scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
            scoreElement.innerHTML = score;
        });
    };
}

function updateTimer() {
    timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
    if(timeLeft >= 0)
        $("#timer").html(timeLeft);
    else {
        gameOver();
    }; 1000;
}

function start() {
    timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    updateTimer();
    $("#playAgainButton").hide();
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var img = createImage();
        game.appendChild(img);
    }, 1500);
}

function ResetGlobalVariables() {
    score = 0;
    timer = 15;
    timeLeft = 15;
}

const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset-button")
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", ResetGlobalVariables)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="game"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="text">
            <p id="gameTitle">Find Greenie!<img src="green-ball.png" alt="Logo"></p>
            <p id="score">Current Score: 0</p>
            <p> You have: <span id="timer">15</span> seconds remaining!</p>
            <button id="playAgainButton" onclick="start()">Go!</button>
            <input id="reset" type="button" class="reset-button" value="Reset">
            <p> You scored: <span id="lastScore"></span></p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Click on Greenie the green ball to score points</p>
            <p>Click Reset and then Go! to restart</p>
            <script src="find.js"></script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: At a glance, there are a variety of things wrong with the `createImage` function.  There's code *after* a `return` statement (so that code will never execute), you're adding an event listener *to a string*, not to a DOM element, you're adding the same event listener multiple times, etc.  This may be a good time to take a step back and re-think the design entirely.  Instead of creating (and destroying?  and re-creating?) `<img>` elements, why not have all of your `<img>` elements in the DOM already and dynamically shown/hidden?  Then just add the click handler to the one you want.

Comment: What's the reason for declaring the `imagesArray` like you do instead of `const  imagesArray = [ "./green-ball.png", "./yellow-ball.png", "./blue-ball.png", "./light-pink-ball.png", "./purple-ball.png"];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate the event listener to the game container.
You need to check the clicked ball is green

You can remove the code after the return img since nothing will be executed after a return

```
game.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('img')) return; // not a ball
  if (!tgt.src.includes('green')) return; // not green
  score++;
  scoreElement.innerHTML = score;
});
```

```js
var imagesArray = [
  "./green-ball.png",
  "./yellow-ball.png",
  "./blue-ball.png",
  "./light-pink-ball.png",
  "./purple-ball.png",
];
let score = 0;
let timer = 15;
var interval;
let timeLeft = 15;
let lastScore = 0;

var img = document.createElement("img")
const images = document.getElementsByClassName(imagesArray);
var game = document.getElementById("game");


function gameOver() {
  var lastScoreElement = document.getElementById("lastScore");
  clearInterval(timer);
  clearInterval(interval);

  $("#playAgainButton").show();
  $("#lastScore").show(
    lastScoreElement.textContent = " " + score
  );
  ResetGlobalVariables;
}

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createImage() {
  img.src = imagesArray[random(0, imagesArray.length - 1)];
  img.width = random(50, 200);
  img.height = random(50, 200);
  img.style.left = random(0, 800 - img.width) + "px";
  img.style.top = random(0, 600 - img.height) + "px";
  img.alt = img.src.split('/').pop(); // to show the colour 
  return img;
}

function updateTimer() {
  timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
  if (timeLeft >= 0)
    $("#timer").html(timeLeft);
  else {
    gameOver();
  };
  1000;
}

function start() {
  timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
  updateTimer();
  $("#playAgainButton").hide();
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    var img = createImage();
    game.appendChild(img);
  }, 1500);
}

function ResetGlobalVariables() {
  score = 0;
  timer = 15;
  timeLeft = 15;
}

const resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset-button")
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", ResetGlobalVariables)
const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");

game.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('img')) return; // not a ball
  if (!tgt.src.includes('green')) return; // not green
  score++;
  scoreElement.innerHTML = score;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="game"></div>
    </td>
    <td id="text">
      <p id="gameTitle">Find Greenie!<img src="green-ball.png" alt="Logo"></p>
      <p id="score">Current Score: 0</p>
      <p> You have: <span id="timer">15</span> seconds remaining!</p>
      <button id="playAgainButton" onclick="start()">Go!</button>
      <input id="reset" type="button" class="reset-button" value="Reset">
      <p> You scored: <span id="lastScore"></span></p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Click on Greenie the green ball to score points</p>
      <p>Click Reset and then Go! to restart</p>
      <script src="find.js"></script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To improve the script, you could have all balls hidden on the page and toggle between one visible using the random number

Comment: I was wondering if you would know how to make the balls appear constantly throughout the game? At the moment they are appearing one every 1.5 seconds but I want there to be multiple balls on the screen appearing randomly throughout the game. Thanks

Comment: Please ask a new question and remember to add the [mcve]